# Body onload handler in a content page 

Tags: c#, javascript, master-pages

How do I call a Javascript function on the body load of a content page? As I can not use the body load of my master page's body `onload` in this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ASP.NET Ajax, then you can add a load handler on your content page:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(contentPageLoadHandler);

function contentPageLoadHandler() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Using this approach, every content page or even every control, can setup its own load handler. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx) for more information.

---

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, you can achieve the same by using this approach (on your content page):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

See [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) for more information.

Comment: If you're using the DOM, whilst less accurate you can do document.onload() = function() { }

Comment: @Kezzer: if you use that approach on both the master page *and* the content page, only one of them will be executed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a [StartupScipt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) in your master page

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("name", script);
```

Answer (score 1):

Successful attempt by using `window.onload`:

```
window.onload=function(){
 foo();
}
```

Comment: Please note: if you have this code on both the master page *and* the content page, only one of them will be executed!

Comment: this is really bad - assigning directly to onload overwrites any previous value. The recommended practice is addEventListener/attachEvent (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) which any library will encapsulate for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you already handled the issue time ago, just to the googlers, in fact you can use the onload from your master page, the con' is that you'll have to put the same name of the javascript function you call on everypage, maybe empty in some cases...